# two dynamic sized side-by-side containers with ellipsis on left container

Tags: html, css, dynamic, ellipsis

Is it possible to have 2 elements inside a container, floating side-by-side. The right element should be dynamically sized to fit the content exactly and the left element should fill the remaining space of the container and have an ellipsis to cut of excess content.

```
---------------------------------------------
|[left element with lots of conte...][right]|
---------------------------------------------
```

The closest I got was this: http://jsfiddle.net/xsr71pak/

But both table cells use 50% of the table. I don't need to use tables, but it was the closest result to what I wanted. Could someone help with this?

Comment: what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: As I said, what I have leaves a 50% width for each container. andi's solution below is exactly what I was looking for. You'll also notice if you change the content in the right div, it will adjust the width dynamically to fit the word/content exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost the same as what you have, but instead of the table, just use divs.  The right floated one would come first in the HTML to make the floats line up properly.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">Something</div>
    <div class="text-ellipsis">This is really long text, long test, long test, long test, long test, long test long text, long test, long test, long test, long test, long test long text, long test, long test, long test, long test, long test</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xsr71pak/1/

Comment: this one did the trick! It was exactly what I was looking for and was also the simplest solution! Thank andi! Can't believe I missed. I tried out divs first, but maybe the right div being first made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understanded you well and that this will help you:

```
<style>
.container {
            border: 1px solid black;
            position: relative;
        }
        .info {
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .dynamicWidth {
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
        .staticWidth {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 30px;
            top: 25%; /*centers the content of this div in middle of height*/
        }
#div1 {float:left;}
</style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="dynamicWidth">
            <div id="div1">Title element</div>
            <div id="div2" class="info">Text: This is a text which should be break with 3 dots when it is bigger then its parent div</div>
        </div>
        <div class="staticWidth">BUT</div>
    </div>
```

[demo of code above](http://jsfiddle.net/zrinja/vg2v7aow/1/)

Comment: Not quite what I wanted because the right div uses a static width (width: 30px;). I needed the right div to fit the content exactly. In your example, it breaks if I change the word in the "staticWidth" div to anything bigger than 30px.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ug5k3k15/5/. It does require a bit of javascript which I will explain below:

```
var widthContainer = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth; 
/* gets the width of the container */

var widthText = document.getElementById('text').offsetWidth; 
/* gets the width of the text */

var widthRest = widthContainer - widthText; 
/* calculates the left-over space. This will result into a number like 500 */

document.getElementById("rest").style.width = widthRest + "px"; 
/* tell the computer what the width of #rest should be. You have to add " + "px" ", else this will just result into a number, and css doesn't understaind numbers.
```

Comment: not what I was looking for and the jsfiddle doesn't even seem to work properly. Thanks for the effort. I think the javascript is excessive in something that can be done purely with HTML+CSS